# Create span with input value

Tags: javascript, append, createelement, createtextnode

I'm trying to get the value of an input, and create an element with the value text in it.  I don't know why this isn't working.

(And, yes!  I called the function.  Just didn't post the jQuery enter key code.)

```
<input type="text" id="user-input"/>

 function submitUserMessage(){
    var message = document.getElementById("user-input");

    if(message.value){
        var userMessageElement = document.createElement("span");
        var userMessageElementText = userMessageElement.createTextNode(message.value);
        userMessageElement.appendChild(userMessageElementText);
        userMessageElement.className = "umsg";
        userMessageElement.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
        document.body.appendChild(userMessageElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying you're using jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call `document.createTextNode()` instead of `userMessageElement.createTextNode()`